# Unexplained Horizontal Scrollbar

Tags: html, css

I've been developing a website for my FIRST robotics team.  However, recently a horizontal scrollbar has appeared which seems to have no explanation.  No elements protrude past the edge of the page, and it works fine in IE.  I can fix it with `body { overflow-x:hidden )` but I'd rather find the true culprit.  Any help would be appreciated.  The site is wordpress-based, and can be found [here](http://mechtechdragons.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the reason on line 22 vender-extension-style.css

try to remove this

```
#header-cut-out {
    -moz-transform: skew(-45deg);
}
```

line 28 vender-extension-style.css below css on img tag

```
#header-cut-out img {
    -moz-transform: skew(45deg);
}
```

your scroll will remove and you have to work on it to get the desired output.

Comment: All I had to do was change the size of the image slightly.  I missed that entirely, thanks.